# VB to C# - Can't read XML

Tags: c#, vb.net, xml-parsing

The VB code in the first chunk works fine and does what it says on the tin, however, I am now converting this to C# and can't for the life of me work out what's up with it.

I have tried running the C#, however, I noticed that combobox2 does not populate. On further digging, I found that my statement `name = xxxxxx` does not actually return anything.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    ComboBox2.DataSource = null
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox2.Text = ""
    Dim name =
        From nm In xelement.Elements("Version")
        Where CStr(nm.Element("Trunk")) = ComboBox1.Text
        Select nm

    For Each xEle As XElement In name
        Dim branches = xEle.Elements("Branch").ToDictionary(
           Function(k) If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(k.Value), k.Attribute("Name").Value, k.Value),
           Function(v) If(v.Attribute("Path") Is Nothing, "", v.Attribute("Path").Value))

        Console.WriteLine(xEle)
        ComboBox2.DataSource = New BindingSource(branches, Nothing)
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Key"
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Value"
    Next
End Sub
```

---

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox2.DataSource = @null;
    ComboBox2.Items.Clear();
    ComboBox2.Text = "";
    var name = from nm in xelement.Elements("Version")
               where System.Convert.ToString(nm.Element("Trunk")) == ComboBox1.Text
               select nm;

    foreach (XElement xEle in name)
    {
        var branches = xEle.Elements("Branch").ToDictionary(k => string.IsNullOrEmpty(k.Value) ? k.Attribute("Name").Value : k.Value, v => v.Attribute("Path") == null ? "" : v.Attribute("Path").Value);

        Console.WriteLine(xEle);
        ComboBox2.DataSource = new BindingSource(branches, null);
        ComboBox2.DisplayMember = "Key";
        ComboBox2.ValueMember = "Value";
    }
}
```

---

extract of xml

```
<Version>
        <Trunk>Software Version 7.2</Trunk>
            <Branch Name=".24777 (Internal)" Path="T:\2014\Product\xxxxxxxxx\Internal\Internal"/>
             <Trunk>Software Version 7.4</Trunk>
        <Branch Name=".103 (Internal)" Path="T:\2015\Product\xxxxxxx\ Internal\Internal"/>
```

Comment: I'm assuming ComboBox1 has appropriate text that matches your where statement (confirmed through debug)?

Comment: I don't think you want to `Convert.ToString` an `XElement` because it will contain xml tags and I'm guessing that doesn't match `ComboBox1.Text`. Does that really work in VB?

Comment: Should it be `where nm.Element("Trunk").Value == ComboBox1.Text`?

Comment: OMG @ParrishHusband i didn't spot that you are correct good sir that is exactly what i need to do. if you type that as an answer ill mark as answered :)

Comment: The `CStr(nm.Element("Trunk"))` is calling the [public static explicit operator string](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,3367036406d1344a) conversion method of XElement to convert it to a string.  That method  returns its `Value` property.  Similar to `(string) nm.Element("Trunk")`.

Comment: @TnTinMn thank you for that link, that is extremely informative.  I've never understood the behavior until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>VB.NET may be doing a 'smart' conversion with `CStr` on `XElement` to retrieve the value</s>.

Edit:  Thanks to [TnTinMn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2592875/tntinmn) for pointing out this is due to the [explicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/explicit) on `XElement` returning `element.Value` when casting to a `string` via `CStr`.

[image]

In your C# conversion, the invocation of `System.Convert.ToString()` behaves much differently.  It first checks for `IConvertible/IFormattable`implementations, and if those don't exist will call `.ToString()` on the object passed in.  Since this is not overloaded on `XElement`, the result will be the the fully qualified name of the runtime type (in this case `"System.Xml.Linq.XElement"`).

Therefore in C# you'll need to change the comparison to either the `.Value`:

```
var name = from nm in xelement.Elements("Version")
           where nm.Element("Trunk").Value == ComboBox1.Text
           select nm;
```

or with the additional understanding of the `explicit operator`, cast to a string:

```
var name = from nm in xelement.Elements("Version")
           where (string)nm.Element("Trunk") == ComboBox1.Text
           select nm;
```

A significant portion of the refactoring I do is unfortunately in VB.NET code bases, and it's amazing how many little issues like this can lurk behind the scenes.

Comment: once again thank you! i'm converting a lot of code and have come across a lot of "little issues" but couldn't figure this one. haha never been great at seeing whats right in front of my face :)